# How to prevent matching single quotes that have white space on their right?

Tags: regex

The following regex is made to match single quotes that should be replaced by smart right single quote ( ’ ):

[image]

It works. But as you can see, it shouldn't match the one in `'*text*`. So I modified the regex:

```
(\S)'(?!\b)|(?=\b)'(?=\b)
```

The problem now is that it's not only matching the quotes but the other punctuation too:

[image]

I'm not a regex expert so I'm not sure how to do it so that only the single quotes are matched in the new regex.

Comment: So why it shouldn't match `*text*` as there is no whitespace after single quote on right?

Comment: `(?=\b)` matches exactly the same as `\b`. There's no need to use a lookahead there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreference of your captured group #1 in replacement to get back what you've matched using `(\S)`:

```
var re = /(\S)'(?!\b)|(?=\b)'(?=\b)/g; 
var str = 'text, \'*text* text?\'\n*It\'s text couldn\'t I\'d text.\'*';

var result = str.replace(re, '$1’');
```

**PS:** Your regex can be shortened to:

```
/(\S)'\B|\b'\b/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mP5xQ7/2)

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but I think you're trying to match a single quote if it's ***not preceded by a whitespace***. The following regex uses a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert it's in a position preceded by `\S` (a non-whitespace character).

```
/(?<=\S)'/g
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6aM2/1)</kbd>